# Spring Boot Security error: Encoded password does not look like BCrypt, converting from in memory authentication to database authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am getting the error : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt

Here is my Configuration class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/h2-console/**", "/createUser")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();

    http.csrf()
            .ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console/**");
    http.headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .sameOrigin();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    String userbyUsernameQuery = "select username, password, '1' as enabled from auth_user where username=?;";
    String rolebyUsernameQuery = "SELECT auth_user.username, auth_role.role_name as authority from auth_user\n" +
            "INNER JOIN auth_user_role ON auth_user.auth_user_id = auth_user_role.auth_user_id\n" +
            "INNER JOIN auth_role ON auth_role.auth_role_id = auth_user_role.auth_role_id\n" +
            "WHERE auth_user.username =?";

    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
            .usersByUsernameQuery(userbyUsernameQuery)
    .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolebyUsernameQuery);

}
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}
}
```

I can post my database if necessary although I don't think it has anything to do with the database.

```
INSERT INTO auth_user (auth_user_id, first_name, last_name, username, password, enabled)
VALUES (1, 'John', 'Test', 'username', 'password', 'yes');

INSERT INTO auth_role (auth_role_id, role_name, role_desc)
VALUES (1, 'ADMIN', 'Admin role'),
(2, 'USER', 'User role');

INSERT INTO auth_user_role (auth_user_id, auth_role_id)
VALUES (1, 1);
```

I am submitting this to the database and I am entering username and password as the username and password on my spring boot application however it gives me that error and I cannot figure out what is wrong as the "fixes" I have seen have literally been what I have here.

Need some pointers as to where to go from here or what is specifically wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you store the password in the database ?

Comment: I store it as a default string just now

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer to my question which was adding this

```
    @Bean
public static NoOpPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return (NoOpPasswordEncoder) NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
}
```

Since my password is stored as a default string I need to use this.
I changed my AuthenticationManagerBuilder configuration method to include this.

```
       auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery(userbyUsernameQuery)
    .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolebyUsernameQuery)
    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same `passwordEncoder` to encode your password into the DB, here is an [example](https://github.com/chao-luo/stackoverflow/tree/Q55829669).

```
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder =
        PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                .withUser("user")
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode("password"))
                .roles("USER")
                .and()
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                .withUser("manager")
                .password("password")
                .credentialsExpired(true)
                .accountExpired(true)
                .accountLocked(true)
                .authorities("WRITE_PRIVILEGES", "READ_PRIVILEGES")
                .roles("MANAGER");
    }
```

Comment: Yeah that is for in memory authentication. How would I do that with a database.